# How optimize copy and paste process for windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystems, copy-paste

When user ot program copy a large file on the same physical disk windows do the following algorith:

```
1. Read a piece of data from disk.
2. Write a piece of data to disk.
3. Do points 1. and 2. until whole file is not written fully.
```

If disk is HDD this process require a time because HDD's head need to go from read point to write. So if I copy a file manually to the separate disk it is faster because disk will read and write data with stream speed.

It is all obvious. So is it possible to configure a file windows system to copy large file to the "cache" disk first and then copy it back to original when file system receive copy command on the same physical disk?

Comment: How big of files are you talking about?  What would trigger a copy to the "cache" disk? I really don't think that would help, sounds a lot slower.

Comment: About 3 Gb or more.

Comment: When I copy ~3Gb file as common it takes ~80 sec, when I copy it to separate disk and copy back it takes ~40-45 sec. 2 times faster.

Comment: that is likely because much of your data is already in RAM. scan/seek time has no impact on what you are describing.that would only be the case if there were many small files.

Comment: if you want to test, try coping the file to the cache drive, and then reboot. After it boots back up try copying it back. I'd guess that it takes closer to the original 80 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible without modifying system code.

Additionally, I think you are overestimating the time wastage associated with scanning and seeking from the source physical address space and the destination physical access space on the disk.

unless the system is desperately short on RAM, the "piece" as you put it that is read is rather large, during which only one scan/seek has occurred. The rest is sequential reading. This data is sent to the IO controller and then to the system bus, is buffered in RAM, and then into the CPU IO Module for processing. this continues until the buffer is cleared, and then the CPU gives the instruction to write the data out to the disk. At that point we get another scan/seek to find the destination address space, and begin a sequential write.

so, generally speaking, READ/WRITE sequential IO time is going to dwarf Random Access time to switch locations. The larger the "piece" read, the less time of the total operation is used for repositioning the heads.

Scan and seek time is a significant performance drag, but only with large numbers of smaller files, where the disk has to reposition very often in order to complete the task, compared to the amount of time its actually transferring data to the CPU. Beyond that, for every file, the NTFS metadata must be read and perhaps written, so the disk must reposition to at least two distinct places for each.

Also windows is a multi-process system, so its likely more than one party will be asking the disk to read or write to different locations. There is no likelihood that your process would have exclusive access to the resources that would prevent multiple IO operations from occurring, and causing you to reposition every time your process sleeps, pulses or becomes active. If you were to change the way windows behaved, other processes than that single copy would also be using the cache drive all the time, so your process would be repositioning it as often as the source drive over the course of the operation.

In the end, the only way your approach could work, is if happening in the background predicting that you wanted to cache a file in advance. otherwise you are just adding complication and obtaining no real benefit.

---

Edit:
As for what will help you, consider getting small SSD (32GB perhaps) and use it for [IO caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost). Windows will fill it automatically as it has time and opportunity, and the more files you cache, the less time you spend reading from disk (though more cache means more cache management required).

Keep your mechanical disks (not SSDs) well defragmented and make sure you are not filing your drives too full. IO takes longer and files fragment more as the drive fills up.

or best of all, if you don't need huge capacity, get an SSD, and Problem Solved!